# Create a Task List Template In SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, template

I am working on a Project Management site and trying to standardize tasks. I have searched the internet and cannot find anything. The publishing features are enabled but I don't know what to do after that.

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR; Did you look at the different types of Apps/Lists you can create in your site yet? A Task App would give you a decent start for standardizing tasks.**

The first suggestion I'd offer is to get clearer on your problem and communicating it as a question. As a side note, here's a solid write up on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

What you have described is quite vague. What do I mean by that?

- Have you created a custom list or a task list app?
- Are you familiar with Content Types? They are VERY useful for developing lists. If you started with a task list app your list will already have a Task content type already installed with the list.
- The advantage of the Task list app is that it will give you a fairly decent starting set of columns. Fields like Task Status are very useful. However, I can't remember the last time I built a task list and didn't do my own thing with it. The idea of someone entering 1% complete would make my teeth ache. However, percentage complete can be used by Gantt views in task lists (which is a decent reason to start with a Task app.

Comment: Thank Carewen but to better clarify the situation: 1. I added a task list app to the page 2. The tasks and subtasks to the page. 3, What I want to do is create a template with those tasks and subtasks to be used as a template for project management.

Comment: If you "save list as a template" then it will create a copy of the list in question along with its structure (columns and views). This could serve your purpose. However, I have found that there can be some minor complications so this is definitely something to test (beyond scope for a comment). You could save it as a template and create a test list to see if it meets your requirements. You can most likely ignore the "include content" option. There is a size constraint on templates and lists with large sets of records do not make for good templates.

Answer (score 0):

A Microsoft SharePoint project task list displays a collection of tasks that are part of a project.

[image]

For more information you could refer to this official article:
[Create and manage a project task list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-manage-a-project-task-list-466ad207-46fd-4c77-9af1-41bc23cec21a)

Comment: I know how to create and manage a SharePoint list. The issue is I want to create a standardized task list and save it as a template for future use. I can save regular lists as templates but tasks wont save.